# TestScheduler not working on RxJava

Tags: java, rx-java

I'm trying to test a function where elements of a stream are dispatched one by one after a delay, I was able to get my tests working using `Thread.sleep`. However, when I use the `TestScheduler.advanceTimeBy` I can't get any result.

Check out the code:

```
public Observable<Object> getDelayedObjects(Observable<Observable<Object>> objectsStreams) {
    objectsStreams.concatMap(objectsStream ->
        objectsStream.repeat().concatMap(object ->
            Observable.just(object)
                      .delay(getDuration(object), TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)));
}
```

And the test code:

```
TestScheduler testScheduler = new TestScheduler();
BehaviorSubject<Observable<Object>> objectStreamSubject = BehaviorSubject.create(objectsStream);

model.getDelayedObjects(objectStreamSubject)
        .observeOn(testScheduler)
        .subscribeOn(testScheduler)
        .subscribe(testSubscriber);

testScheduler.triggerActions();
//Thread.sleep(900) works with the default scheduler
testScheduler.advanceTimeBy(900, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
testSubscriber.assertReceivedOnNext(objects);
```

### Update:

Checking around for `TestScheduler` usage I found out that is usual to pass the scheduler to the `delay` function. So I was able to get the tests to pass by providing the scheduler as an argument to the method `getDelayedObjects` and then to `delay`. However, I still did not get why it was not working before.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `delay` operator, by default, uses the [computation scheduler](http://reactivex.io/RxJava/2.x/javadoc/io/reactivex/schedulers/Schedulers.html#computation()) for performing time based delays. This information can be found in the [documentation](http://reactivex.io/RxJava/2.x/javadoc/io/reactivex/Observable.html#delay(long,%20java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit)) of the method. Look for the value in `@SchedulerSupport` annotation, which in this case is `io.reactivex:computation`.

For testing purposes you will have to replace the computation Scheduler with a [`TestScheduler`](http://reactivex.io/RxJava/2.x/javadoc/io/reactivex/schedulers/TestScheduler.html). To be able to replace, you will have to use [one of the many overrides](http://reactivex.io/RxJava/2.x/javadoc/io/reactivex/Observable.html#delay(long,%20java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit,%20io.reactivex.Scheduler)) of `delay` operator that takes in a `Scheduler`.